# Is it possible to add a "check if previous" column to a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 that I want to use for a report in SSRS 2008.

The main problem is that I have to use two different datasets in one table and cannot do grouping as I want it. Both datasets come from this view. Let's say in one column of my report table I want to sum all computers of all school buildings of my country. In the other column, the ratio students of schools per computer.

Now, in DB there are two different tables one for Buildings and one for Schools (because sometimes there are different buildings for one school or other similar scenarios). Joining them results in more couples building-school than needed for the computer-sum column, it will result summing different times the same building (if more than one schools operate in that building).

The table is this:

[image]

To avoid this I have done those two datasets, one from the building point of view, and one from the school point of view. But these are two datasets in one table! To solve my problem, I have thought to add a special column to my view : it checks automatically if a `BUILDING_ID` is shown twice or more in the result table, f.e. like this:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know if this is possible and if it is, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How do you define a previous column, i see no id nor a timestamp

Comment: That's what I don't know.How to recognize previous BUILDING_ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can give you a hint:

```
select building_id, 
row_number() over (partition by building_id order by newid()) - 1 check_if_previous
from yourtable
```

If you just want 1's or 0's

```
select building_id, 
cast(row_number() over (partition by building_id order by newid()) - 1 as BIT) check_if_previous
from yourtable
```

Comment: I implemented this in another view (for another report), but like this:  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FOLDERS.SERIAL,SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_NAME
ORDER BY NEWID()) - 1 CHECK_IF_PREVIOUS_SCHOOL`.A folder is a location of the school, so there are some schools that operate in different locations, these are counted as different schools (one school ---> two locations = two schools).But every time I execute the view/query it gives me different count of CHECK_IF_PREVIOUS_SCHOOL = 0. ????

Comment: @Harri yes, the first will be random. As i asked earlier: How do you define a previous column. Since you didn't define a sort order. I picked a random order. I realize that could be a problem. But you didn't provide a column for my order by.

Comment: By the way, now I understand what you meant with "defining the previous column".I use the column SCHOOL_NAME in my ORDER BY clause.And I use that column when testing my view as a simple query, because I cannot use ORDER BY in a view. SSMS gives me an error if I try that.

Comment: I have put in top of my `SELECT` clause the column `SCHOOL_NAME`, and changed `order by newid()` in `order by SCHOOL_NAME`.The result is still changing from one "View Report" to another.But now with less difference (1 -3 values).

Comment: @Harri You can add more columns in the order by if you seperate them with comma. That could improve the uniqueness

Comment: I tried that too, but with no success.The result keeps changing from execution to execution.